# In an Angular (>= 2) application, how to include version information from npm package.json file into the compiled output files?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, package.json

**Information:**

1. I have created an Angular (version >= 2) application using `@angular/cli`.
2. This application is undergoing version changes.
3. I do keep the semantic version information of my application updated inside my `package.json` file using the command `npm version major` or `npm version minor` or `npm version patch`.
4. I was unable to find this version information inside any files on the "dist" output folder when I run `ng build` or `ng build --prod`.

**Question:**

Is there a way to bring my application's version information automatically from the package.json file into one of the output files (perhaps inside an html file or a js file)?

Sample from my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "angular-ui",
  "version": "17.6.27",
  "description": "My awesome UI application",
  "license": "MIT",
  ...
}
```

Ideally, I would want to create an "about" component where I would like to publish my application's version information when I visit a URL similar to:

http://localhost:4200/about

**Expected Output on the page:**

```
Application version: v17.6.27
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom script that will read information from your package.json and run `echo "export const APP_VERSION = $version" > src/app/version.ts`.

Then you call this script before the build.

If you create your app with ng-cli, you should already have script entries in your package.json. Something like :

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "changelog": "standard-changelog",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

You can replace **build** by something like

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "sh version-script.sh && ng build",
}
```

I think you can find some fancy tools that do that better than a poor script.sh, and wired them before the build.

Comment: This looks like a good idea. Thanks @Noémi Salaün, I'll try this out and let you know how this goes.