# How can one expose only the package.json version in an Angular 17 application?

Tags: angular, npm, version, package.json

I have a package.json with a version I want to be able to display on the UI of my web application. The issue I run into when importing the package.json is that it will expose the entire contents of the package.json. Is there a clean solution to only extract the version and leave the rest of it's contents un-exposed? This is for security reasons of course.

My current approach was to use the version from the package.json:
`{ "name": "example", "version": "0.0.1", }`

and display it by importing it like so:
`import { version } from '../../package.json';`

Importing the version that way will however expose the entire file, as I can see from developer tools which you can see in the image I attached.

[Exposed package.json in DevTools][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDV4p.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In an Angular (>= 2) application, how to include version information from npm package.json file into the compiled output files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833181/in-an-angular-2-application-how-to-include-version-information-from-npm-pa)

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around by using an npm package called `node-env` which allows me to set the node environment variable for the version, which is then accessible to my Angular application with `process.env.['VERSION']`.

package.json script example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "cross-env VERSION=$npm_package_version ng build",
  },
```

`

It then is accessible like this in your component:

`version = process.env?.['VERSION'] ?? 'Unknown Version';`

Comment: do give the the green tick also to close the answer!

Comment: Will do once my account is old enough.

Answer (score 0):

> Disregard this answer, the `package.json`'s content is indeed exposed.

In your `environment.ts`, add a property like the following:

```js
export const environment = {
  version: require('../../package.json').version,
  // ...
}
```

Adjust the `package.json` path to your liking and the version will be available like this:

```js
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
const version = environment.version;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that leads to my exact issue. The idea is that when it gets imported it becomes exposed. 
However; I found a work-around by using an npm package called `cross-env` and setting the node environment variable in the package.json itself.

Comment: You're right, it exposes the content of `package.json`. Never noticed that. Good to know.